# How to create JSON file from DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

I have created a `DataTable` from the SQL Server. The code is given below

```
protected void BindGridviewData()
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=INBDQ2WK2LBCD2S\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 10 * from test4 order by Id desc", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);


    }
```

Now how do I create `JSON` File from the data table

Comment: Did u try any code ? I think there are many different JSON serialization . check this http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: please see I add link in my answer where you can find Json.net example with binary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, new Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting());
```

Comment: `JsonConvert` is not there. I have added `using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;` namespace

Comment: `Serialization.DataTableConverter()` is not available in JSON.NET

Comment: `Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Net20, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' is not marked as serializable.` I am having this particular error while debugging

Answer (score 1):

I use this method for converting datatable to json.

- I create a class that contains the columns name

For example

```
internal class myObj
{
    public string PrimaryKey{ get; set; }
    public string FirstColumn{ get; set; }
    //And so on...
}
```

Then I convert the dataTable in a List of Obj

```
private List<MyObj> test(DataTable dt)
{

    var convertedList = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
               select new MyObj()
               {
                   ID = Convert.ToInt32(rw["ID"]),
                   FirstColumn = Convert.ToString(rw["FirstColumn"])
                   //etc...
               }).ToList();

    return convertedList;
}
```

Finally I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)` (take from JSon.Net take a look [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Then I serialize the list

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test(myDataTable));
```

Comment: and how do I use this file for creating highchart?

Comment: and can you tell me what is meant my `test`?